# scroll the scrollbars of an iframe from outside the iframe

Tags: jquery

i am opening a page inside the iframe from the same domain. i am trying to scroll the iframe content using jquery. but its scrolling the main browser contents (scrollbars) instead of the iframe contents.

```
 <iframe id="scaled_frame" src="<?php echo $url;?>"></iframe>
```

i am using the following line to scroll the iframe content.

```
$("#scaled_frame").scrollTop(200);
```

how can i scroll the iframe contents.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code:

```
$("#scaled_frame").contents().find("body").scrollTop(200);
// or
$("#scaled_frame").contents().scrollTop(200);
```

the iframe not have content for that page you must find contents after that set scroll.